# The alias does not work ?

Tags: alias

I create an alias in ~/.cshrc like this

```
alias bw  "bjobs -w | awk '{print $7}'"
```

but it doesn't work at $7. How do I fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try seeing what **csh** has defined your alias to, by typing this at the command prompt:

%   alias bw

> bjobs -w | awk '{print }'

What happened? the shell expanded a shell variable named $7, which happens to be nothing, and stuffed that null value in the alias definition.

So this suggests a solution itself, we need to quote the dollar in the $7, away from the prying eyes of the shell, so that it is entered literally into the alias' definition:

%   alias bw "bjobs -w | awk '{print "\$"7}'"

Now when we test what the alias is:

%   alias bw

> bjobs -w | awk '{print $7}'

and this is exactly what you would type at the command line!

To perform the writing of the alias definition, we perform it in 3 steps:

```
 - The quoting is done by closing the double quotes just before the $ to
            come out of the alias' quoting.
 - Now the $ needs to be escaped via a backslash to stop it from being 
            expanded before the alias takes effect.
 - Start the double quotes to re-enter the alias' quoting.
```

** I wish I could draw  this thing pictorially which makes it very trivial to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
alias bw 'bjobs -w | awk '\''{print $7}'\'''
```

`csh` quoting is painful.

Comment: This is not a problem that exists only in `csh`. The same problem applies to shells that implement the `ksh` like `alias` command, since the `alias` parameters in both cases need to go two times through the parser.  The `Bourne Shell` for good reason implements a method to  view and edit raw aliases.

Comment: @schily Hmm, but in `ksh`, I can only just escape `$` in `$7`. no?

Comment: If you like to have single quote characters inside a string surrounded by single quote characters,  you always have this problem.

Comment: Let me give an example with the Bourne Shell and an alias that I use to check man pages while writing them: `alias mroff` prints: `mroff='dosh '\''soelim "$@" | tbl | nroff -u1 -Tlp -man - | col -x'\'' mroff'` while `alias -raw mroff`prints: `#b mroff    dosh 'soelim "$@" | tbl | nroff -u1 -Tlp -man - | col -x' mroff` The command `dosh`is a Bourne Shell builtin to have inline shell scripts for parameterized aliases.